# get negative D, when I try to generate private key RSA

Tags: java, algorithm, rsa, private-key

I have the method to calculate D(private key) for RSA. The method uses extended Euclidean algorithm. So sometimes I get negative D and it isn't right how I can fix it?
D * e mod (p-1)(q-1)=1;
here is the code of the method

```
public static BigInteger extEuclid(BigInteger a, BigInteger b)
{

        BigInteger x = BigInteger.ZERO, y = BigInteger.ONE, lastx = BigInteger.ONE, lasty = BigInteger.ZERO, temp;
        while (!b.equals(BigInteger.ZERO))
        {
            BigInteger q = a.divide(b);
            BigInteger r = a.mod(b) ;
        a = b;
        b = r;

        temp = x;
        x = lastx.subtract(q.multiply(x));
        lastx = temp;

        temp = y;
        y = lasty.subtract(q.multiply(y));
        lasty = temp;
    }

    return lastx;
}


public void calcD(){
  d = extEuclid(e, fEuler);
}
```

Comment: What is D? Where is it in the function you posted?

Comment: That's terrible naming. Your `solve` method should be called `modularInverse` and `b` should be `modulus`.

Comment: Have you tried adding the modulus to `d` if it is negative and then check whether the encryption/decryption cycle works?

Comment: @ArtjomB. don't understand. For example my **modulus** is 56 and I got D=-24....and?

Comment: @ArtjomB. I just should add modulus `D = D + modulus`?

Comment: yes, if D is negative.

Comment: @JamesKPolk,@ArtjomB.  Thanks!!!, it seems work, but decryption process is soooo long.